# ¿Porqué cuando hago pruebas de comportamiento con Behat junto con Dusk no pasa las pruebas?

Tags: laravel-5, behat

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5 este es mi **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.0",
        "behat/behat": "^3.4",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "laravel/dusk": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que cuando ejecuto la prueba usando dusk (artisan dusk) corre perfectamente, y cuando la ejecuto con behat da error. A continuación dejo los ficheros involucrados en las pruebas

[image: Ficheros involucrados]

**FeatureContext**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use \PHPUnit\Framework\Assert as Assert;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends DuskTestCase implements Context
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Given estoy en la pagina principal
     */
    public function estoyEnLaPaginaPrincipal()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }

    /**
     * @Given no estoy logueado
     */
    public function noEstoyLogueado()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @Then debo ver Laravel
     */
    public function deboVerLaravel()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
}

Cambio el primer escenario por
return Assert::assertTrue(true, 'No paso la prueba');
```

**prueba.feature**

```
# language: es
  Característica: Prueba
    Para saber si se tiene acceso a la pagina principal
    Como un usuario anonimo
    Necesito posicionar el navegador en el index

  Escenario: Pagina principal
    Dado estoy en la pagina principal
    Y no estoy logueado
    Entonces debo ver Laravel
```

**ExampleTest**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

**DuskTestCase** (Este ya viene generado)

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless'
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Ahora los errores son los siguientes

Característica:: Prueba
  Para saber si se tiene acceso a la pagina principal
  Como un usuario anonimo
  Necesito posicionar el navegador en el index

Escenario: Pagina principal         # features\prueba.feature:7
    Dado estoy en la pagina principal # FeatureContext::estoyEnLaPaginaPrincipal()
      Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu"]}}}

```
  Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException)
Y no estoy logueado               # FeatureContext::noEstoyLogueado()
Entonces debo ver Laravel         # FeatureContext::deboVerLaravel()
```

--- Failed scenarios:

```
features\prueba.feature:7
```

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m9.18s (9.27Mb)

Y este es el resultado cuando corro **behat** (removiendo el código que lanza el navegador a visitar la url $this->browse(...)

Característica:: Prueba
  Para saber si se tiene acceso a la pagina principal
  Como un usuario anonimo
  Necesito posicionar el navegador en el index

Escenario: Pagina principal         # features\prueba.feature:7
    Dado estoy en la pagina principal # FeatureContext::estoyEnLaPaginaPrincipal()
    Y no estoy logueado               # FeatureContext::noEstoyLogueado()
    Entonces debo ver Laravel         # FeatureContext::deboVerLaravel()
      TODO: write pending definition

1 scenario (1 pending)
3 steps (2 passed, 1 pending)
0m0.64s (9.10Mb)

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada para usar laravel dusk necesitaba que mi clase FeatureContext.php extendiera de DuskTestCase, ya eso estaba saldado desde el comienzo. Segundo debía llamar a la función setUp de la clase Laravel\Dusk\TestCase que es la encargada de establecer la configuración necesaria para comenzar a utilizar el navegador. Tercero tendría que ejecutar el ChromeDriver manualmente desde la consola, pues de lo contrario siempre la conexión sería rechazada, y cuarto si deseaba que el navegador se volviera a cerrar debía crear un campo estático que tuviera una instancia de la clase **Laravel\Dusk\Browser**, con la cual podría ser llamada su función **quit()** en un método estático al final de correr todos los escenarios de la característica actual.

Comando para ejecutar el webdriver de google chrome desde la consola

```
"./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-win.exe" --verbose
```

Resultado final del archivo FeatureContext.php

```
<?php
@include_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends \Tests\DuskTestCase implements Context
{
    /** @var  Browser $browser */
    static $browser;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @Given Que Estoy en la pagina principal
     */
    public function IamHomePage()
    {
        $this->browse(function (\Laravel\Dusk\Browser $browser) {
            //Establezo una instancia del navegador para poder cerrarlo cuando corran todas las pruebas
            self::$browser = $browser;

            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }

    /**
     * @Then Debo ver el texto Laravel
     */
    public function mustSeeLaravelText()
    {
        return true;
    }

    //Se ejecuta una vez se terminen de probar los escenarios
    /** @AfterSuite */
    static function _tearDown()
    {
        self::$browser->quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones bro! Que hayas encontrado tu mismo la respuesta, es genial y que te hayas tomado el tiempo para redactarla compartiendo con la comunidad, sencillamente admirable. Éxitos con el proyecto, ¡Dale con todo el power 2.0! Bendiciones :D

Comment: jajaja OKOK palante que todavia me falta un mun2 Gracias ;P

Comment: de nada bro :D Gracias por compartir :D